# Unable to start JMeter 4.0 client with SSL RMI

Tags: ssl, jmeter, rmi

I am trying to run a simple test on a remote JMeter 4.0 server from a JMeter 4.0 client.
Both are configured to use the same **rmi_keystore.jks**. The server starts fine and listens on RMI and Server Engine ports.
When I try to start the client if fails with the **java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)** error. netstat shows that no process is listening on this port.

```
2018-06-08 01:04:38,934 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2018-06-08 01:04:38,955 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/user.properties
2018-06-08 01:04:38,955 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/system.properties
2018-06-08 01:04:38,955 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: java.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:38,962 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2018 The Apache Software Foundation
2018-06-08 01:04:38,962 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 4.0 r1823414
2018-06-08 01:04:38,962 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_171
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2018-06-08 01:04:38,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =2
2018-06-08 01:04:38,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2018-06-08 01:04:38,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2018-06-08 01:04:38,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/opt/apache-jmeter-4.0
2018-06-08 01:04:38,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/data/blah-blah-blah
2018-06-08 01:04:38,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/data/blah-blah-blah
2018-06-08 01:04:38,972 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: x.x.x.164 Name: client.domain.local FullName: client.domain.local
2018-06-08 01:04:38,976 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/data/blah-blah-blah'
2018-06-08 01:04:38,983 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/data/blah-blah-blah'
2018-06-08 01:04:39,290 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2018-06-08 01:04:39,317 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2018-06-08 01:04:39,324 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 4.0
2018-06-08 01:04:39,334 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: SimpleHttpRequest.jmx
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,403 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2018-06-08 01:04:39,416 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary>
2018-06-08 01:04:39,423 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: x.x.x.169
2018-06-08 01:04:40,286 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines
2018-06-08 01:04:40,288 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Fri Jun 08 01:04:40 UTC 2018 (1528419880286)
2018-06-08 01:04:40,288 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2018-06-08 01:04:40,296 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2018-06-08 01:04:40,296 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2018-06-08 01:04:41,108 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,108 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,111 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-06-08 01:04:41,114 INFO o.a.j.r.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/x.x.x.164,localport=50100]]
2018-06-08 01:04:41,125 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2018-06-08 01:04:41,125 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2018-06-08 01:04:41,127 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,127 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,130 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: Error replacing class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement by wrapper: class org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerWrapper
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 50100; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /x.x.x.164 using port 50100
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerImpl.<init>(RemoteThreadsListenerImpl.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ConvertListeners.addNode(ConvertListeners.java:66) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:135) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:149) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1013) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:915) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:543) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /x.x.x.164 using port 50100
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:139) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        ... 22 more
2018-06-08 01:04:41,156 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname': x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,156 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Local IP address=x.x.x.164
2018-06-08 01:04:41,158 ERROR o.a.j.e.ConvertListeners: RemoteException occurred while replacing Remotable item.
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 50100; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /x.x.x.164 using port 50100
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteSampleListenerImpl.<init>(RemoteSampleListenerImpl.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ConvertListeners.addNode(ConvertListeners.java:80) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:135) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:149) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1013) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:915) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:543) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not bind to /x.x.x.164 using port 50100
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:139) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.jmeter.rmi.SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        ... 22 more
2018-06-08 01:04:41,246 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
2018-06-08 01:04:41,250 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
2018-06-08 01:04:41,250 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.threads.RemoteThreadsListenerTestElement
2018-06-08 01:04:41,251 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

This is in **jmeter.properties** on the client.

```
...
client.rmi.localport=50100
...
```

Command line to start the client

```
jmeter -n -X -Rx.x.x.169 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.164 -t SimpleHttpRequest.jmx -j jmeter-client.log
```

I wonder if JMeter starts to listen here

```
SSLRMIServerSocketFactory: Created SSLSocket: [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/x.x.x.164,localport=50100]]
```

and then tries to listen on the same port again for some reason.

If I disable SSL for RMI on both the server and the client it works fine but I don't want to do that for security reasons. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does jmeter server has same version 4 installation?

Comment: Yes, both have 4.0 r1823414 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Fixed in JMeter version 5.0

> Bug 62463 - Fix usage of ports, when client.rmi.localport is set for distributed runs.

This is a bug in JMeter 4.0 and will (hopefully) be fixed in 4.1. You might want to track this at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62463

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue in the bug tracker. I'll mark this answer as accepted if the issue is accepted as a bug.

Comment: Error seems to be back in Jmeter 5.4.1

Answer (score -1):

The error you're getting means that there is a some process running which is taking the port `50100` so JMeter cannot use this port.

You can check which process is "holding" the port 50100 using [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command and kill this process, once done JMeter should be able to start successfully.

You can also try setting `client.rmi.localport` value to `0` - this way [RemoteSamplerListener](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/RemoteSampleListener.html) will bind to a random free port.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: If you re-read the post, you'll see _netstat shows that no process is listening on this port_

Comment: I can't use random port due to firewall rules. But interestingly enough, when I set `client.rmi.localport` to `0` JMeter starts listening on three different ports if Secure RMI is enabled. If Secure RMI is disabled, JMeter is listening on one port only.